# What are the benefits of not checking function arguments in python?

Tags: python, type-systems

I'm trying to understand what are the benefits of the fact that python defaults to not checking function arguments.

For example:

```
from some_module import my_function
my_function(some_argument)

# some_argument could be a very complicated data structure 
# made of dictionaries and lists.

# I have to depend on the good will of the developer of my_function
# to get reasonable error logs/exceptions. 

# If the type checks were completed for function arguments on the level of the language
# it would be much clearer that the function is failing because of the wrong structure of the argument
```

The above is an attempt to reason why it would be a positive if type checking for arguments existed as a core functionality of the language.

What are the positive sides of the current status quo (no argument type checks)?

Comment: Type systems are complicated, so many "dynamic" languages like Perl, Python, PHP, Ruby, JavaScript don't have static type checks. This only changed fairly recently, e.g. Python got the `typing` module in version 3.5. Python itself ignores these type annotations, but you can use the external `mypy` tool as a type checker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a real advantage to dynamic languages?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246762/is-there-a-real-advantage-to-dynamic-languages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Simpler, cheaper language implementation.
- Faster compilation or execution (depending on when the checking would run).
- Often better readability of simple algorithms.
- Easier to write flexible functions; e.g. functions that can take scalar and compound arguments (i.e. the aggregate pattern can be used without having to define classes only for that purpose).
- Trade-off between the price and benefit of compile/runtime type checking can be made by the user (after all, the `typing` module exists) rather by having the language making it for him.

There are downsides of course, but it looks as if you already know them.

Comment: Completely missed that `Simpler, cheaper language implementation` might be a reason :D

Comment: Almost certainly not faster execution. Type systems enabled better optimizations, in two ways: 1) they give the compiler more type information 2) they impose restrictions on code. #1 gives the compiler more information to work with (which a JIT might need to figure out for itself, e.g. this function is only ever called with an `Int`, never a `Double`). #2 restricts the possible observable behaviors of a piece of code. The less edge cases there, the more room an optimizer has to change things without violating the "as if" rule.